# I am using the simple_form gem in rails 7 and I am trying to get the options to show what I want intstead of what is given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, simple-form

I am new to ruby on rails and need to use the simple_form gem. I have an association that gets the value that I want so far but when I show the form what I see is something like: #User:0x000001830e64f9a0
I want to change that to whatever I choose (value will be from a database) to show

form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@player) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :User, as: :select %>
    <%= f.input :fname %>
    <%= f.input :lname %>
    <%= f.input :position %>
    <%= f.input :club %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Part of player controller

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_player, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /players or /players.json
  def index
    @players = Player.all
  end

  # GET /players/1 or /players/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /players/new
  def new
    @player = Player.new
    @user = User.select(:username)
  end
```

User model

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :User
end
```

Player model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: `:User` should be changed to `:user` in both places. **Everything** except ClassNames and CONSTANTS should be snake_case in Ruby (and Rails).

Answer (score 0):

as [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) has commented, change :User in both your form and belongs_to relation to :user

Regarding the value of the player instead of getting the value of the object player, you should map your collection with the specific field that you want to display such as:

```
Player.all.map(&:fname) for first name
```

or

```
Player.all.map(&:whatever_value_you_want_to_show_from_DB)
```